# Generalised probability density functions using Dirac deltas

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory, probability-distributions, dirac-delta

I just cannot understand how a discrete random variable $X$ may be represented using a generalised probability density function (p.d.f.) $f_X$ as,

\begin{equation}\tag{1}
f_X(x) = \sum_{x_k \in R_X} P(X = x_k)\delta(x - x_k)
\end{equation}
where $R_X = \{x_1, x_2, ...\}$ is the range of the discrete random variable $X$, $P(\cdot)$ is the probability mass function (p.m.f.) of $X$ and $\delta(x - x_k)$ is the [Dirac delta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function),

$$\delta(x)  = \begin{cases}
    \infty,&  x = 0\\
    0,              & otherwise.\end{cases}
$$

where *by definition* of the Dirac delta function,

$$\int_{- \infty}^{+ \infty} \delta(x)dx = 1$$

I have seen (1) used in a number of online sources. What I do not understand is how (1) works if you end up multiplying infinities? Shouldn't (1) be rewritten as,

\begin{equation}\tag{2}
f_X(x) = \sum_{x_k \in R_X} P(X = x_k)\delta(x - x_k)dx
\end{equation}

where,

$$\delta(x)dx  = \begin{cases}
    1,&  x = 0\\
    0,              & otherwise.\end{cases}
$$

Two online sources where (1) is used:

i. [A book's supporting website](http://www.probabilitycourse.com/chapter4/4_3_2_delta_function.php)

ii. [A tutorial publication (pdf)](http://marionesta.cba.pl/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/2009.pdf)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The point here is that $f_X(x)$ is a probability density function, so it's only ever used to calculate anything in an integral. That takes care of the issue with the Dirac delta function. Basically this is a way to turn a discrete probability distribution $P(X)$ into a continuous one $f_X(x)$.

Comment: Uh oh silly me ^^. This is what not thinking at 2am looks like. Thanks!

Comment: $f_X$ is not a function because $\delta$ is not.